# Can a Shell TabBar have a tab without a content page?

Tags: maui

I have a .Net MAUI app that uses a Shell TabBar for navigation, as described here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/tabs?view=net-maui-7.0

It looks like this:

```
<TabBar>
    <Tab Title="Home" Icon="{StaticResource IconHome}">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}" />
    </Tab>
...
```

Is it possible to have some tabs not associated with any pages, but rather with commands, e.g. making a call or opening a browser etc?

Comment: You can put code in contentpage’s OnAppearing. However I don’t know if OnAppearing has been fixed. See issue https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8102

Comment: @TollmakerSteve Thank you for the idea. As I understand, an Appearing event fires when a page is about to appear on the screen. But I don't want any page to appear, I just need to executed some command (method). Can OnAppearing help with this?

Comment: And as I understand, that issue was with the second page, but I care now only about the first pages, i.e. right after clicking a TabBar's tab. So execution does come to OnAppearing, but I would like to know how I can stop the page from appearing after my code is executed.

Comment: *"I don't want any page to appear, I just need to executed some command"* A work-around is (in OnAppearing) to execute the command, then do a line of code to go back to previously shown tab. I'm assuming Maui Shell's go back method (I forget exact name) will do that. See discussion in Maui Shell Navigation doc.

Comment: Do you want to implement a button-like function on Tabbar?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I tried this from OnAppearing(): await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(".."); which was supposed to send me back to the previous screen, but it did not happen.

Comment: @Dongzhi Wang-MSFT I am not sure how button-like function on TabBar would look. I just need to execute some code upon clicking on a tab, without showing any page.

Comment: @DavidShochet *"it did not happen"* - Put a breakpoint on that line. Is that code called? If not, add this as an issue at `github maui issues`.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Somebody explained to me that it does not go back because the dummy page associated with the tab is not on the navigation stack..

Comment: Hmm. Then it might not be possible to avoid showing that page. Perhaps you can make it appear for a short while, showing a message telling user their command is being executed. Do you want to pursue that approach? Still need to know whether that code is reached (put breakpoint). And need to know whether the go `..` would work, if it was done after a delay. Easiest way to verify that, is to add a button on the page, that executes that go `..`. Let me know if those two tests succeed, then I can say what to do.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Yes, the code is reached. I now save every open page's name in a static variable on the App, and pass the previous one to Shell.Current.GoToAsync(). This way it works. But unfortunately, as I understand, OnAppearing() is called only once. So I cannot call the same functionality again. I don't know how I can work around it...

Comment: There *might* be some way to work around it by writing a custom handler for the page, and intercepting "some" property change in platform-specific code (not sure which property). I would say "wait until they fix it", but unfortunately the OnAppearing issue is currently on "backlog", despite the fact that its a showstopper for some projects that are trying to migrate from Xamarin Froms to Maui.

Comment: @DavidShochet I wrote a demo of Shell TabBar in Maui and tested it. I added breakpoints in the page's OnAppearing() and OnDisappearing(), which are called every time I click or leave the tab. You can try to test it by writing your method in OnAppearing() or OnDisappearing().

Comment: @Dongzhi Wang-MSFT I also placed breakpoints in OnAppearing. After my code, OnAppearing has Shell.Current.GoToAsync(App.CurrentPage) to return to the previous page. And this works. But when after returning to the previous page I click the tab again, the breakpoint is not hit.

Comment: When you use Shell.Current.GoToAsync, the original page has been overwritten, and the new page is displayed in the tab, the OnAppearing method in the original page will not be called. When you click again, the OnAppearing of the new page should be triggered. method.